# GXT 3 extremly slow with Chrome 47.x

Tags: performance, google-chrome, gwt, chromium, gxt

I have a web application build on Sencha GXT 3. With the recent update of Chromium to version 47.0.2526.80 the application runs extremly slow. In contrast, other browsers and even older (e.g. 46.x) or newer (e.g. 48.x) versions of Chrome and Chromium can perform the application very fast. Using the profiler, I can see that `Ext.DomQuery` functions and `byClassName` take about 80% CPU time.

I wonder if there is a known issue in this particular version of Chrome or if my application or gxt/gwt has a bug.